# update NULL value in SQlite

Tags: sqlite

I have a table with a few NULL values in an integer column and I set one of those values to 2.

I have tested the statement by replacing those NULL values with numbers, and the statement updates the values correctly, however whenever I try to update a NULL value, it just stays NULL.

in the context of this app, the value could be either NULL, 0 or 1, and at this point would run an UPDATE command to set the value to 2. it works for the 0s and 1s, and works if i replace null values with something else such as a 9, however it would be convenient to leave them as NULL- But it doesn't update as NULL!

How would I go about fixing this?

Comment: What `update` statement have you tried?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are probably using `WHERE column = NULL` in your UPDATE statement to determine the rows that should be updated.

In SQL, you **can not** compare a value for equality to NULL using the equal sign `=`, the *normal* comparison operator – for targeting NULL-values, you have to use `IS_NULL` instead, so

```
WHERE column IS_NULL
```

Comment: I saw this and tried this, and it failed. So out of curiosity I tried other versions of writing "IS_NULL" and "isNull" works but "IS_NULL" fails. Dunno why, but felt like mentioning it for future viewers.

Comment: UPDATE items
SET "mengeneinheit" = 'stk'
WHERE "mengeneinheit" IS NULL;